# How to run evosuite-generated tests if scaffolding file contains specific configurations for each machine?

Tags: java, testing, configuration, evosuite

I'm working with evosuite 1.0.6 to generate tests for my project, and each test class comes with a scaffolding file that contains a `setSystemProperties` method with machine-specific properties. This makes it difficult to run the tests on different machines without performing manual configurations on each one. I've considered several options, such as removing the `setSystemProperties` method or the scaffolding class, but this could affect the functionality of the tests. I've also thought about using environment variables, but this requires each user to correctly configure these variables on their machine.

I've tried several approaches, such as removing the `setSystemProperties` method and the scaffolding class, and using environment variables to configure the properties. However, these options either affect the functionality of the tests or require manual configurations on each machine. I was expecting to find a way to run the evosuite-generated tests on different machines without having to perform manual configurations on each one.

I'm looking for suggestions or solutions that could help me overcome this problem.